# How to send String class to Activity in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

this is my string where i am added the queuelist.

```
   private lateinit var str_weighment_data: String
     fun enable_data_event():Boolean{
        socket.on(this.data_event_id, object : Emitter.Listener {
            override fun call(vararg args: Any) {

                receive_data_queue.add(args[0] as String)
                msg_recieved.set(true)
                str_weighment_data= receive_data_queue.peek()
                receive_data_queue.remove()
            }
        })
        return false
    }
```

and the data `str_weighment_data` send to the another activity?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
socket.on("a", new Emitter.Listener() {
      @Override
      public void call(Object... args) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent("Action");
            intent.putExtra("KEY",your_data);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
          }
        });

      }
    });
```

and then register the broadcast receive on your activity